# Capture image from UIView is not working on iOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, image-capture

I capture `image` from `UIView` content like below and it's working fine but when i run it in my iPhone5S with `iOS 10.3.3`, Captured `image` contains only Black View.

```
-(UIImage *)captureImageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

What's the issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your code is perfect. Probably there must be any other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that way as explained by @LGP.

**Use following function on main thread like below.**

```
-(UIImage *)captureImageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Main thread code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIImage *imgResult = [self captureImageFromView:yourView];
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `drawViewHierarchyInRect` instead. If this doesn't work either then the problem is likely that you capture the wrong view or after it has been altered in some way.

```
-(UIImage *)captureImageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: @Pankil Is the view on screen when you call `captureImageFromView`?

Comment: View is in `TableViewCell`. I capture selected cell `UIView`.

Answer (score -1):

FOR SWIFT

```
func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
```

FOR OBJECTIVE C

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourview.frame.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, yourview.frame);

    [yourview.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"size %f %f",newImage.size.height,newImage.size.width);

    return newImage;
}
```

Before call hide button etc if you need then that will not show on image also.

Comment: still it generate black image.

Comment: could you please make sure which view you are saving as a image has reference from storyboard also .

Comment: `UIView` inside `UITableViewCell` and i capture selected `UIView`.